# Vue multiple select form independent from each other

Tags: vuejs2

I need a solution how to make as many select form as my option data length and each form must be independent from each other. It means that if i chooce selected value in one form it must do not overide selected value in others form. Also i need pre-set selected value in each form (for the first form  it need to show selected first choice, for second = second choice and so on.)

```js
 var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
    data: {
        selected: '',
        options: [
            { id: 20 , supp_name: 'test1' },
            { id: 21 , supp_name: 'test2' },
            { id: 34 , supp_name: 'supertest' },
          ]


    },
})
```

```html
 <div margin="20px" v-for='option in options'>
    <form action="">
        <select v-model="selected">
            <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.supp_name">
                [[option.supp_name]] 
            </option>
        </select>
        <span>Chosen: [[selected]]</span>


    </form>
</div>
```

It display 3 forms but when I make a choice in on one form it override all forms. How could it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need as many `selected` references as there are forms.

For example

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
  data: {
    selected: [], // make selected an array
    options: [{"id":20,"supp_name":"test1"},{"id":21,"supp_name":"test2"},{"id":34,"supp_name":"supertest"}]
  },
  watch: {
    options: {
      immediate: true,
      handler (options) {
        // initialise to the "supp_name" from options
        this.selected = options.map(({ supp_name }) => supp_name)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(_, i) in selected">
    <form action="">
      <select v-model="selected[i]">
        <option v-for="option in options" :value="option.supp_name">
          [[ option.supp_name ]]
        </option>
      </select>
      <span>Chosen: [[ selected[i] ]]</span>
    </form>
  </div>
  <pre>selected = [[ selected ]]</pre>
</div>
```

This synchronises the `selected` **array** to be the same length as options then binds each form's `<select>` to the array index.

Comment: Phil, thank you for your explanations. but i have another one question. How to pre-set  default valut with value for first form it must be test1, second form - test2, last one - supertest?

Comment: @dmitriy_one I've updated my answer to show how to set defaults

Comment: could you please also show how to add methods which listen if select value was changed?